# OkHttp - Android get Data from MySQL database

Tags: android, okhttp

Hey Im fairly new to android developing and Im currently trying to establish a connection to my database so I can work with the data on my phone.

Im using OkHttp and mysqli with php.

I wrote a handler which accesses the .php pages and makes the database calls.

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private OkHttpClient client = null;

public String latestMessage = "";

public OkHttpHandler(){

    client = new OkHttpClient();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(params[0].toString());
    Request request = builder.build();

    try{
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        latestMessage = response.body().string();
        return response.body().string();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //latestMessage = "failed";
    return null;
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
    public int getSongwriterId(String songwriter) {
    OkHttpHandler okHttpHandler = new OkHttpHandler();
    okHttpHandler.execute(url_get_songwriter_id + "?songwriter=" + songwriter);
    String responseString = "";
    while(responseString == "") {
        responseString = okHttpHandler.latestMessage;
    }
    okHttpHandler.cancel(true);
    Songwriter s = getSongwriterFromJSON(responseString);

    return s.getId();
    }
```

Now, I know that this ugly while(true) is a shitty solution. But how should I do it so Im 100% certain I got my responseString before passing it into "getSongwriterFromJSON"?
I really don't get how that is supposed to work.

The code works all fine when i debug it step by step, but the application just blackscreens from time to time without debug. I guess thats due to the while(true) loop and that probably just runs and runs and clocks up the thread so that my background thread just dies - I really don't know anymore.

Please if you provide help, explain what Im doing wrong, and how I should do it right. Thanks.

Edit php file used:

```
<?php
$response = array();

$con = @mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "Select * FROM songwriter ";
$sql .= "where composerName = '";
$sql .= $_GET["songwriter"];
$sql .= "'";

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// looping through all results
$response["songwriter"] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $songwriter = array();
    $songwriter["id"] = $row["id"];
    $songwriter["composerName"] = $row["composerName"];
    $songwriter["arrangerName"] = $row["arrangerName"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["songwriter"], $songwriter);
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Does your PHP script give a response? Add your PHP script as well

Comment: I just added my php file - yes it does give a response. It works well in debug mode. But wont do its job if i let it run normaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the sync API of OkHttp while there is an [async](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get) one, that you should use:

That `while` is a serious bottleneck, you should remove it asap. Try something like this:

**Request.java**

```
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

/** Very basic Request helper **/
public class Request {

    public static OkHttpClient client = null;

    /**
      * Get the current OkHttpClient or creates a new one if it doesn't exists
      * @return OkHttpClient
      */

   public static OkHttpClient getClient(){

        if(client == null)
            client = new OkHttpClient();

        return client;
   }

    public Call get(String url, Callback callback) {

       okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .get()
          .build();

       Call call = getClient().newCall(request);
       call.enqueue(callback);

       return call;

    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
//...
public interface MyCallback {
   void run(Object data); //Generic callback
}


public void getSongwriterId(String songwriter, MyCallback myCallback) {


   Request.get(url_get_songwriter_id + "?songwriter=" + songwriter, new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        //Handle error
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

         final String body = response.body().string(); //Get API response

         final Songwriter s = getSongwriterFromJSON(body);

         //Remove it if you just need to show the ID in the UI
         myCallback.run(s.getId())

         //OKHttp callback isn't in the main thread, 
         //UI operations need to be run in the main thread
         //That's why you should use runOnUiThread
         MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Handle UI here if needed           
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText(s.getId());

            }
         });
      }
   });
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but you are not supposed to write a `@` in front of `mysqli_connect`:

```
$con = @mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
```

Try to replace it with:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
```

And obviously replace the X'es with your credentials.

If this does not work(or having a `@` in front of mysqli_connect is allowed in php, and you have tried testing after removing it) please run the PHP script from your computer, showing it as a website. Make sure you get any errors visible.

If there is nothing wrong with the PHP script, add `Log.e` tags with a fixed tag into your Java code. Try to see if there is anything wrong there. Make sure the connection actually succeeds as well.

Comment: You do - else you get an networkonmainthreadexception...
Thats the main Reason I need to do all of this async stuff.

Comment: Ignore that part(just removed it too): do the other things

Comment: I did - still wont work.
As I said - everything works fine when i debug and go threw it slowly.
I had a look at every method in my code and all the calls.
As long as I debug it will work step by step.

But when i let my App run without debug it just locks up and doesnt work.
Imo. the problem is the "while(responseString == "") " .